# How to map images outside root spring application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am trying to load images from local disk by using below configuration in dispatcher-servlet.xml.

```
<bean>  
    <mvc:resources mapping="/imageCDN/**" location="file:/L:/JAVA/IDE/imageCDN/"/>
</beans>
```

And trying to access the same in my jsp page,like below.

```
<img alt="" src='<c:url value='/imageCDN/${product.productId}.png'/>' style="width: 100%; height: 300px">
```

But,this how its getting mapped.
[while inspecting the code in browser-musicapp is the root.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnJUk.png)

i am not sure about the approach,can somebody help me to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out,whatever i have configured is correct it was just a tomcat.

Clean the tomcat directory and run it.